# MQL, PHP select all from two tables?

Tags: php, mysql

So i have two tables:

```
order_product

--------------------------------------------------
| ProductID     | Quantity         
--------------------------------------------------

products

-------------------------------------------------------------
| ProductID     | productname | Desc | Price | Stock | Image     
------------------------------------------------------------
```

and i need to get all of the same product ID, show their quantity then times that by their price and show the grand total of all.

My problem is i'm trying to show a checkout page which shows everything in a list, but how do i combine the two tables? Also, there are no foreign keys for the first table.

I need this in an sql statement as well preferably, like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT...'
```

Would this work?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM order_products
UNION
SELECT * FROM products"
```

If so, how do i know which row is which?

My desired output is all entries, now looking like this:

```
ProductID     | Quantity   | Productname | Desc | Price | Stock | Image
```

Comment: connect with product_id ?

Comment: How do i do that in php?

Comment: can you give a sample of the output you wish to get?

Comment: Select all from two tables would be done as: SELECT * FROM order_product op
INNER JOIN products p
ON op.ProductID = p.ProductID; and here's some background information http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: @drne so INNER JOIN gives me: ProductID | Quantity | Productname | Desc | Price | Stock | Image, an example output being: 52, 24, Blackmores, Goode for you, 26.77, 70, gth.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a classical `JOIN` clause:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM products
LEFT JOIN order_products on products.ProductId = order_products.ProductId
```

Comment: How would the table look then?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM products  
LEFT JOIN order_products on products.PRODUCTID = order_products.PRODUCTID";     So this would join the two tables just on my php file right?

Comment: Right. As long as you execute yhis SQL sentence, of course.

Comment: So this would give me table order as:  ProductID | Quantity | Productname | Desc | Price | Stock | Image

Comment: Well, you can adjust selected columns and order with basic SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.ProductID
     , table1.Quantity
     , table2.Productname
     , table2.Desc
     , table2.Price
     , table2.Stock
     , table2.Image 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.productid=table2.productid
```

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is i'm trying to show a checkout page which shows
>   everything in a list, but how do i combine the two tables?

You need to simply use mysql `JOIN` to show `cart` items.

Your table data should be like as i added in demo.

See [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/090311/2)

```
SELECT 
  o.id 'orderId',
  o.ProductID 'pid',
  SUM(o.Quantity) 'qty',
  p.productname  'product',
  p.`Price` 'price' 
FROM
  order_product o 
  INNER JOIN products p 
    ON p.`ProductID` = o.`ProductID`
```

**Edit Required output**

> My desired output is all entries, now looking like this: 
>   ProductID | Quantity | Productname | Desc | Price | Stock | Image

Modify above query's `SELECT` part `SELECT tablename.your_column .....`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what's the output you wish to get is but you should use something like this

```
SELECT o.ProductID, o.Quantity, p.Price, o.Quantity * p.Price
FROM order_product o
LEFT JOIN products p ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join.

```
Select * from order_products op INNER JOIN products p ON p.ProductID = op.ProductID;
```

w.r.t. your need, the above query needs to be modified to:-

```
 "SELECT *,
         SUM(op.quantity * p.price) AS grandTotal
    FROM order_products op
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT p ON p.ProductID = op.ProductID WHERE p.ProductID =".$prodId(your php variable of product id);
```